# make a close button that appears after time on an image

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout

Basically I want to add a "x" , a close button, at the top right of an image that will appear after some time using `setTimeout()`. So when you click on the x button, it will close the image. I played around with `<input type="image">` but it isn't what I wanted because it makes the image clickable. I've looked at examples but I'm not sure how to approach this. Thank you for any help.

```js
function showImage(){
     document.getElementById('banner').style.display = 'inline-block';  
}
setTimeout(showImage,3000);
```

```html
<figure class = "showBanner">
     <input type="image" id="banner" src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1" style="display:none"/>
     <script type = "text/javascript" src = "testing.js"></script>
</figure>
```

Comment: You have to put that JS code inside of a click listener on that "x" button

Comment: You shouldn't load your js inside an element. It goes either at the beginning or end of the document.

Comment: I'd recommend turning your code into a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) runnable snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: The `<input type="image" ... />` is for formulas when you want to have a button with background-image. As far as I understand, that is not at all what you want.

Also, use a separate css-file for your styles!

This example should solve your problem:

```js
function showButton(){

        document.getElementById('xButton').style.display = 'block';   
}

document.getElementById('xButton').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('banner').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('xButton').style.display = 'none';   
});

setTimeout(showButton,3000);
```

```css
#xButton {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.showBanner {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<figure class = "showBanner">
  <button id="xButton"> x </button>
      <img src="https://i0.wp.com/wptavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/stack-overflow.png?ssl=1" id="banner" width="100%">
       
</figure>
```

Comment: srry was away for some time. Thanks! i can use this as a guide to make some fixes on mine!

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the opacity from 0 to 1 on click, this way you can use css transitions too

```
style="opacity:0"

banner.style.opacity = '1';
```

As for the button you can use the x symbol

```
<span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>

const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.closeBtn');
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => banner.style.opacity = '0');
```